# Unsupported Video Chipset - How do I force Low-Graphics mode?

Tags: 11.04, video

I'm a Ubuntu noobie - but I got my laptop dual-booted with XP and Ubuntu 11.04, with all updates installed.

I have a Dell Inspiron 5160 with an XGI Volari XP5 video card. It supports 640x480 - 32/16/8 bit color, 800x600 - 32/16/8 bit color, and 1024x768 - 32/16/8 bit color.

I'm pretty sure this is an unsupported chipset for Linux. But, the low-graphics mode works fine when I boot in recovery mode.

How can I set this as my standard video configuration?

Comment: Have a look at this one http://askubuntu.com/a/871621/18140

Answer (score 4):

You could try adding one or more grub boot options such as "nomodeset" and "xforcevesa" - see my linked answer for help on how to do this.

You can try to use one of the following combinations:

```
nomodeset

xforcevesa

nomodeset xforcevesa
```

---

If you boot into recovery-mode you could create a file call `xorg.conf`:

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

copy and paste the following information:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier  "Configured Video Device"
    Driver      "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier  "Configured Monitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier  "Default Screen"
    Monitor     "Configured Monitor"
    Device      "Configured Video Device"
EndSection
```

This is the very basic framebuffer driver that fail safe uses.

Possibly if you change the text `Driver     "fbdev"` to `Driver     "vesa"` this should give you slightly better VESA type graphics.

This [wiki page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man4/trident.4.html) refers to the "trident" video driver. Since your card is a trident you may possibly be able to change the driver to "trident".

This [wiki page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man4/sis.4.html) refers to the "SiS" video driver which contains the "XGI Volari" name of your graphics card - possibly your card is this type in disguise and you may be able to change the driver to "SiS"

---

Linked Question:

1. [How do I set 'nomodeset' after I've already installed Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-to-set-nomodeset-for-installation/38834#38834)

Comment: Fossfreedom, I tried all the combos (xforcevesa, nomodeset, xforcevesa nomodeset) and they all gave the same blank screen. Any other ideas?

Comment: VGA compatible controller: Trident Microsystems XGI Volari XP5 (rev 02). Free -m shows 495 MB Mem and 255 MB Swap.

Comment: I'm planning on running exactly one thing: Dummynet, so I'm hoping it will be sufficient.

Comment: Thanks fossfreedom. The "stock" xorg.conf you gave boots me into a CLI mode "Ubuntu 11.04 ubuntu tty1" then "ubuntu login:". The Gnome gui is gone (I've removed Unity due to hardware limitations). I'll try the driver variations.

Comment: When booting from failsafe mode you'll see a file called `/etc/X11/xorg.failsafe` - have a look at it - if it is different from what you have tried, try `sudo cp /etc/X11/xorg.failsafe /etc/X11/xorg.conf` and rebooting.

Comment: Aha, I think we have success, by using the Driver "vesa" variation. It seems to be booting back into low graphics mode successfully. Thankyou very much for your help.

Comment: Yes, failsafe is using Driver "vesa".

Comment: And one further update: SiS goes to the CLI (no GUI) and trident gives a blank screen. So for the "vesa" is the only choice that works correctly.

Comment: excellent - if you are happy with the answer - just click the accept button.

Comment: Thanks, "nomodeset xforcevesa" fixed a black screen when attempting to use a live CD Xubuntu (13.10) session on a SiS GPU for me. :)