# Force VESA driver in Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: drivers, graphics, xorg, gpu-driver, i915

My Ubuntu 16.10 uses i915 driver. For some reasons I have troubles with it. So I want to force X to use VESA.

I tried:

1. `blacklist i915` in `/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf`. Then `sudo update-initramfs -u`. Doesn't work.
2. `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash modprobe.blacklist=i915"` in `/etc/default/grub`. Then `update-grub2`. Doesn't work
3. Added new file `20-foo.conf` in `/usr/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d` with content:

   ```
   Section "Device"
       Identifier      "Configured Video Device"
       Driver          "vesa"
   EndSection
   ```

Doesn't work.

Guys, how on the Earth one could make an OS that requires such an effort just to switch video driver? Maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Try adding "sisfb" to the `/etc/modules` file, or even renaming/moving all xorg-related config files.

Comment: Didn't work. Also tried to add `vesa`. Moving xorg.conf.d caused X to not work at all.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with a different card and Ubuntu 16.04.

I had luck appending a kernel parameter at boot: `vga=791`

The `vga` parameter sets the framebuffer to [VESA mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VESA_BIOS_Extensions#Linux_video_mode_numbers) 791 (1024x768 16bit).

To add kernel parameters: [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/19487/18140) or the [wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters).

HTH