# Nouveau blacklisted but loaded

Tags: 18.04, nouveau, nvidia-prime, modprobe

Hi I am trying to use Ubuntu-Prime for ubuntu 18 on an asus laptop with 2 GPU (intel & nvidia).

I found the power consumption of the computer to be way too high when I reboot with only the intel GPU (using `prime-select intel` or using `nvidia-settings`).

I found that the nouveau driver was loaded despite normally not used:

```
$ gpu-manager | grep nouveau
Is nouveau loaded? yes
Is nouveau blacklisted? yes
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"
Found "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"
Skipping "/dev/dri/card1", driven by "nouveau"
```

I tried to blacklist it and also have a kernel startup option to prevent nouveau from being loaded *yet it still loads*. This seems very un-linuxy to me.

Comment: Is the nvidia driver loaded?  Post the whole output of gpu-manager.  Blacklisting doesn't prevent something from explicitly loading a driver, so something must be pulling it in, maybe because Nvidia's not loaded.

Comment: No nvidia is not loaded. I would actually like my discrete GPU to be off to prevent it from draining the battery.

Comment: What video driver are you trying to use, Vesa?  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/849481/force-vesa-driver-in-ubuntu-16-10  There might even be another framebuffer fallback driver possible.

Comment: I do not see why I would need a driver for a graphic card supposedly off ?

Comment: Digging the issue, Ubuntu 18 has a conflicting service (with prime) that actually loads a driver for the discrete GPU :
 ```
systemctl status nvidia-fallback.service 
● nvidia-fallback.service - Fall back on nouveau if nvidia is not loadedLoaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-fallback.service; enabled; vendor preset: enable
       Active: active (exited) 
      Process: 1007 ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe nouveau --config /(code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
     Main PID: 1007 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    XX systemd[1]: Starting Fall back on nouveau if nvidia is not loaded

Answer (score 7):

I found a way to disable nouveau and get my battery life back when using prime with intel graphic card :

2 bugs in Ubuntu 18 are concerned :

## 1. Prime fails to turn off discrete GPU ([known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/+bug/1763978)).

Make sure that your discrete GPU is connected to PCI port 0000:01:00.0 (using `lspci -vnn | grep '\''[030[02]\]'` for instance)

Change `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service.wants/nvidia-prime-boot.service` and replace the current execstart (referencing vgaswitcheroo which is not usually available by `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "echo 'auto' > '/sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:01:00.0/power/control'"`)

## 2. nvidia-fallback loads nouveau when nvidia is not loaded

Even if we are willing not to use the discrete gpu !

Disable the following service which loads nouveau driver when nvidia driver is not loaded : `sudo systemctl disable nvidia-fallback.service`

Comment: `/etc/systemd/system/display-manager.service.wants/nvidia-prime-boot.service` was just a symlink to `/lib/systemd/system/nvidia-prime-boot.service` and it's gone in the latest `nvidia-prime` package version, `0.8.8.1` that is in `bionic-proposed`.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone suffering with this: I was just about to try Antonin's solution but didn't need to after installing prime 0.8.8.1 from bionic-proposed. I had the nouveau issue with nvidia-390/restricted, nvidia-prime/main, nvidia-settings/main. Currently using nvidia-396 from graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu.

system: Dell Precision 7730 on 18.04 w/ Intel i915 and Quadro P4200

Assuming bionic-proposed and graphics-drivers/ppa/ubuntu are enabled:

```
sudo apt purge nvidia* && sudo apt autoremove --purge  
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-396 nvidia-prime/bionic-proposed nvidia-settings
```

*reboot

Now prime-select no longer triggers a grub update or loads nouveau. And nvidia-fallback.service seems to have vanished.

```
gpu-manager | grep nouveau
```

returns

> /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
>   /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
>   /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
>   /etc/modprobe.d is not a file
>   Is nouveau loaded? no
>   Is nouveau blacklisted? no

and
`lspci -nnk | grep -iA2 VGA`

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:3e94]
>   Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0832]
>   Kernel driver in use: i915
>
> 01:00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation Device [10de:1bb9] (rev a1)
>   Subsystem: Dell Device [1028:0832]
>   Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Previously nouveau was loaded for 01:00.0

[nvidia-prime 0.8.8.1](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-prime/0.8.8.1)

Comment: I had this same problem and fixed this way. The only difference is that, after purging all NVIDIA related stuff, I reinstalled it with the `.run` file from Nvidia. Did not need to install any `nvidia-prime`, it did everything by itself and now no nouveau loaded. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.